# How to access parameter *name* for the given *class*?

Tags: python, class

**Given class:**

```
Class Tank:
 def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.alive = True
    self.ammo = 5
    self.armor = 60
```

**Followed by:**

```
tanks = {"a":Tank("Alice"), "b":Tank("Bob"), "c":Tank("Carol")}
alive_tanks = len(tanks)

if alive_tanks > 1:
      for tank_name in sorted(tanks.keys()):
         print(tank_name, tanks[tank_name])
```

**Wanted output:**

```
a Alice
b Bob
c Carol
```

**Actual output:**

```
a <__main__. Tank object at 0x000001E5AC7192E0> #and so on.
```

If possible, how can you get an output string formatted as:

*A) Alice*

*B) Bob*

*C) Carol*

Comment: I have no idea how to get parameter **name** for class **Tank**. Haven't found an explanation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create class and use `self` in it to define variables, it means those are attributes. These attributes can be access by using `<class_name>.attribute_name`, so in your case, the code would simply be:

```py
if alive_tanks > 1:
    for a,b in tanks.items(): # Something like ((k1,v1),(k2,v2),(k3,v3))
        print(a,b.name) # or print(f'{a.upper()}) {b.name}')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
[image: solution]

**Note:**

```
Tank('name').attribute = attribute
```

In this case,

```
Tank('Bob').name = 'Bob'
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

String formatted as *wanted*.